# Android permission to drop shortcut

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have the following permissions in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

Despite having the needed permissions the app still crashes:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT from pid=5022, uid=10043
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:3609)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:893)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:421)
       at com.myapp.app.BaseFlavorExtensions$ThirdPartyAppShortcutHelper.createAppShortcut(SourceFile:648)
       at com.myapp.app.BaseFlavorExtensions$InstallAndDeleteAPKsServiceExtension.onDirectAPKOfferInstalled(SourceFile:276)
       at com.myapp.services.InstallAndDeleteAPKsService$3$1.doInBackground(SourceFile:458)
       at com.myapp.services.InstallAndDeleteAPKsService$3$1.doInBackground(SourceFile:444)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: have you already added permission `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />` in AndroidManifest ?

Comment: Just realized that I do have the permission.